# how to make direct link to website in telegram-bot-php button?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

good night guys, i want to ask about telegram bot with php. my problem is i need my button to be a directlink to website. here is my code

```
if ($text === "Website") {
$txt = 'http://www.dpmptsp.sidoarjokab.go.id';
apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 'parse_mode' => 'html', "text" => $txt));
}
```

when i click  the button in telegram, it just print the link. Any suggestion to make the button just directing to website without print it and i need to click the link again?

Comment: are you trying use InlineKeyboards? You can add inline button with url, that can be opened by clicked,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it doesn't support directly open without click at this time, for Telegram very cares about user privacy.

If you use HTML markup, you can send link like `<a href="https://www.sean.taipei>Click Me</a>`, might have better UX.